# Using Eclipse BIRT Report Designer via PHP

Tags: php, classnotfoundexception, birt, php-java-bridge

I want to use Birt Reports in an php webproject.
Therefore I installed the recommend Java Bridge and the BIRT Runtime
by moving JavaBridgeTemplate621.war and birt.war to my Tomcat.

After that I wrote a short class calling the BirtEngine:

```
try {
    $ctx = java_context()->getServletContext();
    $this->birdEngine = java("org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine")->getBirtEngine($ctx);
    java_context()->onShutdown(
        java("org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine")->getShutdownHook()
    );
} catch (java_InternalException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

As I recognize that `$e->getMessage()` returns `""` I take a look at the catalina.out and there I found this exception:

```
23.03.2011 15:02:43 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor handleMessage
INFO: AttachmentInInterceptor skipped in HTTP GET method
23.03.2011 15:02:43 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor handleMessage
INFO: StaxInInterceptor skipped.
23.03.2011 15:02:43 org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor handleMessage
INFO: ReadHeadersInterceptor skipped in HTTP GET method
23.03.2011 15:02:43 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doIntercept
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation:
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.URIMappingInterceptor.handleMessage(URIMappingInterceptor.java:77)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:92)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:285)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:168)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:175)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.doGet(AbstractCXFServlet.java:157)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518)
        at php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445)
        at php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:444)
        at php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500)
        at php.java.bridge.http.ContextRunner.run(ContextRunner.java:145)
        at php.java.bridge.ThreadPool$Delegate.run(ThreadPool.java:60)
```

Especially this line takes my attention:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine
```

But each try to get help from google and common websites failed.
So I hope someone from this site can help me.

Comment: To which recommendation are you referring? Have you tried var_dump() or reflection on the Exception returned? Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Your class cannot find the BIRT engine.  Where did you deploy the class attempting to access the engine?  In its own context?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I do run BIRT through the PHP java bridge successfully. The PHP code you have is correct. But the way that you are using the WAR files is not.

Basically you one war file with both the PHP/JavaBridge files and BIRT + a special class to load BIRT within the JAVA bridge.

If you still haven't solved this problem, I might be able to make the WAR file I'm using available.

Comment: hi do u know how to implement birt with help of zend javabridge

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having a problem calling BIRT from php here's [very good tutorial](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363642/Intergrating-BIRT-with-PHP) that helped me a lot.